# Fix and debug the error with entity framework core meny to many relation . what I am getting in this poject

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I am getting an error with my Entity framework core code first project. please help me!

Error:
"FK_Event_Keyword_Connect_Event_FK_EventId". The conflict occurred in database "D:\NW_PROJECT\NW_SERVER\NIGHTWORKS.ENDPOINT\BIN\DEBUG\NET6.0\DATABASE\NWDATA.MDF", table "dbo.Event", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.'

My Code:
Event Table:

```
[Table("Event")]
public class NWEvent
{
    public NWEvent()
    {
        Creationtime = DateTime.Now;
        //Files = new HashSet<_File>();
    }

    [Key][DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)][Required]
    public string EventName { get; set; }

    public DateTime Creationtime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Startingdate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Endingdate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(2000)][Required]
    public string EventText { get; set; }


    [NotMapped]
    [JsonIgnore] //nem volt itt
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(User))]
    public int Owner_Id { get; set; }

    //public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    /*
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Address))]
    public int Address_Id { get; set; }
    */

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Address))]
    public int Address_Id { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [JsonIgnore] //nem volt itt
    public virtual List<Event_Keyword_Connect> Event_Keyword_Conns { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [JsonIgnore] //nem volt itt
    public virtual List<Event_User_Connect> Event_User_Conns { get; set; }

    public virtual List<_File> Files { get; set; }

}
```

Keyword Table:

```
[Table("Keyword")]
public class Keyword
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public virtual List<Event_Keyword_Connect> Event_Keyword_Conns { get; set; }
}
```

Connect table:

```
[Table("Event_Keyword_Connect")]
public class Event_Keyword_Connect
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    

    [NotMapped]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual NWEvent Event { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Event))]
    public int FK_EventId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Keyword Keyword { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Keyword))]
    public int FK_KeywordId { get; set; }

    
}
```

Relation:

```
//Event <--> Keyword
        mb.Entity<Event_Keyword_Connect>()
            .HasKey(pt => new { pt.FK_KeywordId, pt.FK_EventId });
        mb.Entity<Event_Keyword_Connect>()
            .HasOne(y => y.Keyword).WithMany(y => y.Event_Keyword_Conns)
            .HasForeignKey(y => y.FK_KeywordId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        mb.Entity<Event_Keyword_Connect>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Event).WithMany(x => x.Event_Keyword_Conns)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.FK_EventId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

Data:

```
public static void LoadData(ModelBuilder mb)
    {
        List<NWEvent> events = new List<NWEvent>();
        List<Address> addresses= new List<Address> ();
        List<Keyword> types = new List<Keyword>();
        List<Event_Keyword_Connect> etcs = new List<Event_Keyword_Connect>();
        List<Event_User_Connect> eucs = new List<Event_User_Connect>();


        NWEvent e1 = new NWEvent()
        {
            Id = 1,
            EventName = "ProbaEvent1",
            Startingdate = new DateTime(2021, 12, 15, 15, 30, 00),
            Endingdate = new DateTime(2021, 12, 15, 18, 00, 00),
            EventText = "[Event1] This is our test events text. This text will fill de body od our posts",
            Address_Id = 1,
            Owner_Id = 1

        };
        NWEvent e2 = new NWEvent()
        {
            Id = 2,
            EventName = "ProbaEvent2",
            Startingdate = new DateTime(2021, 12, 15, 15, 30, 00),
            Endingdate = new DateTime(2022, 01, 03, 00, 00, 00),
            EventText = "[Event2] This is our test events text. This text will fill de body od our posts",
            Address_Id=2,
            Owner_Id = 1

        };
        NWEvent e3 = new NWEvent()
        {
            Id = 3,
            EventName = "ProbaEvent2",
            Startingdate = new DateTime(2021, 12, 15, 15, 30, 00),
            Endingdate = new DateTime(2022, 12, 15, 18, 00, 00),
            EventText = "[Event3] This is our test events text. This text will fill de body od our posts",
            Address_Id = 2,
            Owner_Id = 2

        };
        events.Add(e1);
        events.Add(e2);
        events.Add(e3);

        Address a1 = new Address() { 
            Id = 1,Longitude= 19.0891178,
            Latitude = 47.5818847,
            City = "Budapest", 
            Country = "Hungary", 
            Street="Ady Endre u.", 
            BuildingNumber = 3, 
            PostalCode = 1044 };
        Address a2 = new Address() { 
            Id = 2,
            Longitude= 20.1436765, 
            Latitude= 46.25701189999999, 
            City = "Szeged", 
            Country = "Hungary", 
            Street = "Mérey utca", 
            BuildingNumber = 13, 
            PostalCode = 6722 };
        Address a3 = new Address() { 
            Id = 3,
            Longitude= 18.229786, 
            Latitude= 46.072483, 
            City = "Pécs", 
            Country = "Hungary", 
            Street = "Bajcsy-Zsilinszky utca", 
            BuildingNumber = 5, 
            PostalCode = 7622 };
        addresses.Add(a1);
        addresses.Add(a2);
        addresses.Add(a3);

        Keyword et1 = new Keyword() { Id = 1, Name = "Dance" };
        Keyword et2 = new Keyword() { Id = 2, Name = "Party" };
        Keyword et3 = new Keyword() { Id = 3, Name = "Biking" };
        types.Add(et1);
        types.Add(et2);
        types.Add(et3); 

        Event_Keyword_Connect etc1 = new Event_Keyword_Connect() {Id=1, FK_EventId = 1, FK_KeywordId = 1};
        Event_Keyword_Connect etc2 = new Event_Keyword_Connect() {Id=2, FK_EventId = 1, FK_KeywordId = 2 };
        Event_Keyword_Connect etc3 = new Event_Keyword_Connect() { Id = 3, FK_EventId = 2, FK_KeywordId = 1 };
        Event_Keyword_Connect etc4 = new Event_Keyword_Connect() { Id = 4, FK_EventId = 2, FK_KeywordId = 2 };
        etcs.Add(etc1);
        etcs.Add(etc2);
        etcs.Add(etc3);
        etcs.Add(etc4);

        Event_User_Connect euc1 = new Event_User_Connect() { Id = 1, EventId = 1, UserId = 1 };
        Event_User_Connect euc2 = new Event_User_Connect() { Id = 2, EventId = 1, UserId = 2 };
        Event_User_Connect euc3 = new Event_User_Connect() { Id = 3, EventId = 2, UserId = 1 };
        Event_User_Connect euc4 = new Event_User_Connect() { Id = 4, EventId = 2, UserId = 2 };
        eucs.Add(euc1);
        eucs.Add(euc2);
        eucs.Add(euc3);
        eucs.Add(euc4);

        mb.Entity<NWEvent>().HasData(events);
        mb.Entity<Address>().HasData(addresses);
        mb.Entity<Keyword>().HasData(types);
        
        mb.Entity<Event_User_Connect>().HasData(eucs);
        mb.Entity<Event_Keyword_Connect>().HasData(etcs);

    }
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Do the insert statements run in the right order?

Comment: As far as I can see yes

Comment: Then you should also be able to see which of the four `Event_User_Connect()`s is the offender.